# Are there any ways to show swagger error message when out of range input in Swagger UI validation of input parameters is given?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui

Are there any ways to show error message in response header in swagger instead of only showing red box?

```
Test([FromHeader(Name="x-test")][Range(1,2, ErrorMessage = "invalid")] 
string requiredHeader)
```

Tested using above code it does not show anything.

```
Test([FromHeader(Name="x-test")][Range(1,2, ErrorMessage = "invalid")] 
string requiredHeader)
```

maybe it can show in the response header "invalid"?

Comment: What red box? Can you add a screenshot that shows the red box and indicates the place where you want to show the error message?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZqKM06N  i did not have enough reputation to upload an image. Anyways, instead of only showing red box, maybe it can show 'invalid' in that box?

Comment: There's no response header on this image. The image shows Swagger UI's validation of input parameters, the request has not been sent yet at this point. Do you mean you want to customize input validation on the Swagger UI page to display an extra message? Or do you want to customize the actual responses from your API in case of invalid data in requests?

Comment: aahh yes, sorry about that. Yes, i wanted to customize the input validation on the swagger ui to display extra message when invalid input is given. Not sure if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Validation errors are currently displayed in tooltips - see https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSUBw.png. To add custom validation messages you'll probably have to fork Swagger UI and implement this yourself. You might have better luck asking this question in the Swagger UI repository at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues.

Comment: okay, thank you for help.